# How to disable bundle minification while building angular app?

Tags: angular, bundling-and-minification

I have developed a angular project and have implemented SSR(Server Side Rendering) using angular-universal package.
I am able to successfully serve my project with SSR at port localhost:4000, But I want to debug it as we do in in source of chrome developer tool.
In SSR the main.js is served but I want all components code without minification.

Is there any way to stop of disable minification??

I have tried with --optimization=false, but no luck.
I should be able to debug whichever component.ts i wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally we use the property `source-map` to `true` to debug.

> --source-map - Output source maps for scripts and styles. For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#source-map-configuration | default: boolean false

[`build docs`](https://angular.io/cli/build)

Comment: thank you so much, Naren. this helps me awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Minification is an optimization that is disabled by default in development mode.

The `--optimization` CLI option you mentioned is only available for `ng build` which is used for deployment. You should use `ng serve` for debugging purposes.

Here is a screenshot showing an exception triggered by a button click. In the Chrome DevTools console, you can see links to source files. When you click any link, the corresponding source file will open in the `Sources` tab with the line highlighted in yellow and cursor positioned at the right column.

[image]